# Certbot renewal error - AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, certbot

I've an **AWS** instance which letsenrypt certificate will expire next week. I'm using **Certbot** for the SSL. 
To renew the certificate i ran :

```
./certbot-auto  --force-renewal
```

Then I got the following error

```
     - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: mydomain.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Incorrect validation certificate for tls-sni-01 challenge.
   Requested
   e1ffb2998151164f701ff76417586854.6bdc1fb9cc4424a3ecd85558d178f6e9.acme.invalid
   from IP.00.00.00. Received 3 certificate(s), first
   certificate had names "mydomain.com"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

My domain name was entered correctly, and my DNS A record(s) contain the right IP. (I'm using 3 for 1 ip like : mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com, myOLDdomain.com).

Can someone help me **renew it** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to update my certificate. Something was wrong with my web directory.

```
sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --expand --webroot --webroot-path /path/to/web/folder -d mydomain.com
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error. Initial certificate works fine, DNS and reverse-DNS set up appropriately. Running Centos7, postfix/dovecot/spamassassin and nginx on an AWS instance. Would not update with nginx running.

When I stopped nginx and ran

```
certbot renew
```

everything worked fine and I just restarted nginx. Not sure if it is a problem with certbot or nginx. I set up my renewal script to stop nginx, renew, and restart nginx when done.